# Why does my boolean for my loop keep being set back to True?

Tags: python, class, pygame, boolean

so im programming a game and it's my first time using classes. I have a class that has different fields for different aspects of a background and objects for the different backgrounds.
I have a while loop for the start screen. This works however when I click on play it's suppose to set start to False and stop the loop but when I press it, it gets set to False once and straight back to True which continues the loop. I use print to see what the boolean is at all times.

I difine start = True at the top of the code

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

start = True



screen_width = 900
screen_height = 507
center_x = screen_width/2
center_y = screen_height/2

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 100

WHITE = (255,255,255)

bgx = 0
bgx2 = screen_width




main_bg = pygame.image.load("mainmenu.jpg")
main_bg2 = pygame.image.load("mainmenu.jpg")
first_bg = pygame.image.load("firstlvl.png")
first_bg2 = pygame.image.load("firstlvl.png")
second_bg = pygame.image.load("secondlvl.jpg")
second_bg2 = pygame.image.load("secondlvl.jpg")
third_bg = pygame.image.load("thirdlvl.jpg")
third_bg2 = pygame.image.load("thirdlvl.jpg")

#for i in range(1,7):
    #pygame.mixer.music.load("music"+str(i)+".mp3")


class layout:

#""" This class makes the layout of each screen (including buttons, music and background)"""       
    def __init__(self, background, background2, back_button, pause_button, play_button):
        self.bg = background
        self.bg2 = background2
        self.backbut = back_button
        self.pausebut = pause_button
        self.playbut = play_button

    def create_screen(self):
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        global bgx, bgx2
        bgx -= 3
        bgx2 -= 3
        screen.blit(self.bg, [bgx,0])
        screen.blit(self.bg2, [bgx2,0])

        if bgx + screen_width == 0:
            bgx = screen_width
        elif bgx2 + screen_width == 0:
            bgx2 = screen_width

        if self.playbut == True:
            butimg = pygame.image.load("playbutton.png")
            butrect = pygame.Rect(center_x-(358/2),center_y-(146/2),358,146)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if butrect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        start = False
                        print (start)

            screen.blit(butimg,butrect)

        if self.backbut == True:
            butimg2 = pygame.image.load("backbut.png")
            butimg2 = pygame.transform.scale(butimg2, (62, 62))
            butrect2 = pygame.Rect(10,screen_height-72,62,62)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if butrect2.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        pass
            screen.blit(butimg2,butrect2)
        if self.pausebut == True:
            pass

        pygame.display.flip() 

main_screen = layout(main_bg, main_bg2, False, False, True)
icon_select = layout(main_bg, main_bg2, True, False, False)
lvl_select = layout(main_bg, main_bg2, True, False, True)
lvl_1 = layout(first_bg, first_bg2, False, True, False)
lvl_2 = layout(second_bg, second_bg2, False, True, False)
lvl_3 = layout(third_bg, third_bg2, False, True, False)


while start:
    print (start)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            start = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    main_screen.create_screen()
    clock.tick(FPS)




pygame.quit()
sys.exit


enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function create_screen() you need to add a line that says `global start` to tell the python interpreter that variable was defined in a different scope.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, let me try that!